# How can we make an item in a listbox invisible or disable in gwtp?

Tags: gwt

```
ListBox list  = new ListBox();
list.addItem("Select an item");
list.addItem("a");
list.addItem("b");
list.addItem("c");
list.addItem("d");
```

How can I make the item "d" invisible?Please help me to sort out the problem.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: If the item should be invisble, why do you even add it to the listbox?

Comment: Nice joke.It depends on the case.What if I want to use it once and disable it?

Comment: So the item should be visible, but not selectable?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the ListBox is not something GWT readily provides. But you can always make a GWT widget invisible using this API -

```
widget.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, It is preety simple.I use the given code for the answer.

```
((Element) list.getElement().getChild(index).getChild(index)).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but someone my come across is. Therefore, this is how you could achieve it

1. Making the item invisible with css style attribute: `display:none` and `display:initial`.

   ```
   private void toggleItem(ListBox listBox, boolean display, int itemNumber) {
   if (listBox == null || listBox.getItemCount() < 0) {
       return;
   }
   Element option = listBox.getElement().getElementsByTagName("option").getItem(itemNumber);
   if (option != null) {
       if (display) {
           option.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.INITIAL);
       } else {
           option.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Making the item disabled with the html `attribute` `disabled="disabled"`. All you need is set the option attribute like this:

   option.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");